# How to load the last url you have opened in a webview

Tags: android, webview

I have:

```
package my.domain.app;    

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.webkit.*;



public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private WebView webView;
    private SharedPreferences sPref;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webapp);
    }

    void someMethod() {
        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

        String url;

        if (sPref.contains("PREFS_ID"))
            url = sPref.getString("PREFS_ID", "DEFAULT_VALUE");
        else
            url = "http://example.com";

        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
        webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
        webSettings.setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);

        MyWebViewClient myWebViewClient = new MyWebViewClient();
        webView.setWebViewClient(myWebViewClient);
        webView.loadUrl(url);
    }

    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (!url.equals("YOUR_FIRSTURL")) {
                sPref.edit().putString(url, "PREFS_ID").commit();
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

I want that he opens http://example.com but if i go to http://example.com/page2 that when I reopen the webview he opens http://example.com/page2 
I have now updated the code with some more details.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply save your url to `SharedPreferences` and then, if url exist in your `SharedPreferences` reopen it.

Like this:

```
void someMethod() {
    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

    String url;

    if (sPref.contains("PREFS_ID"))
        url = sPref.getString("PREFS_ID", "DEFAULT_VALUE");
    else
        url = "http://example.com";

    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
    webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
    webSettings.setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);

    MyWebViewClient myWebViewClient = new MyWebViewClient();
    webView.setWebViewClient(myWebViewClient);
    webView.loadUrl(url);
}

private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (!url.equals("YOUR_FIRSTURL")) {
            sPref.edit().putString(url, "PREFS_ID").commit();
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: How to place this in my script with the websettings

Comment: I updated the code with some more details. I now don't have errors anymore, but when I started the activity I got a white screen.

Comment: he said "Method somemethod() is never used" to

Comment: @Anoniem In thi case, I think you need read about java first... It is never used, because you did not call it from your `onCreate` or where-ever else.
Please, accept my answear.